# Ipad doesnt display images

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

Why iPad doesnt display images on my website?

On comupters everything works fine, but when I run website on iPad, I see only first image.

I tried to add everywhere this same image (first one that works) to all sections but still there is only first one displayed.

Images are in same resolution 1024 x 614, and size < 200kb

Check website: http://www.badzlepszy.pl/Nebiolo/
*check website on computer and iPad, see the difference...*

Code for iPads, tablets

```
<link media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)" href="css/tablet.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Css code for images

```
#kafelobrazintro { 
background: url(../images/introtablet.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat; 
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1920px; 
position: relative; 
box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
overflow:hidden;
}

#kafelobraz1 { 
background: url(../images/logomzblue.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;  
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1920px; 
position: relative; 
box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531580/how-do-i-css-style-differently-between-ipad-and-iphone?rq=1

Comment: This seems shockingly similar to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269310/why-my-webiste-display-only-one-image-on-ipad. I hope you aren't duplicating questions.